# It is possible to kill staph. aureus in tonsils with antibiotics or citricidal?

Tags: antibiotics, staph-infections

It is possible to kill staph. aureus in tonsils with antibiotics? Because i ve heard that it just disappear for few days or weeks. But on the other hand i heard some people heal it with citricidal. Truth is that citricidal makes my tonsils and tongue clearer but i dont know how long i need to drink it (i am using it for 5 days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is vague and could use clarification. Are you having symptoms of a tonsil infection? If so, what? Have you seen a doctor?

First off, **Staph aureus is a normal skin and mouth bacteria**. In the study below, about 40% of patients had S. aureus in their throat on admission (not acquired in the hospital) (1). Since S. aureus is a normal part of our microbiome, **you do not need to take antibiotics to kill it unless you have symptoms of infection**, namely trouble swallowing, sore throat, fever, and pus coming from the tonsils (4). Even if you have tonsillitis, it's unlikely to be caused by staph-- the majority of cases are caused by a virus (4).

What makes you concerned about S. aureus in particular? If you do have symptoms of infection in your tonsils, you should see a doctor. If they think the infection is likely due to staph, they will probably prescribe Bactrim, clindamycin, doxycycline, or cephalexin, though there are many good options (3). There is some evidence that citricidal may have antibacterial properties, but **citricidal has not yet been tested in human subjects so there is no way of knowing how well it works compared to antibiotics**(2).

Again, many people have staph aureus on their skin and in their mouths-- this is not the same as an infection. You do not need treatment unless you have symptoms. If you are concerned, see a doctor.

References:

[Rate of Colonization of Staph Aureus in the Throat](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1594670/)

[Possible Bacteriocidal Properties of Citricidal](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0305417904001743)

[Antibiotics Used for Soft Tissue Staph Infections](https://www.hopkinsguides.com/hopkins/view/Johns_Hopkins_ABX_Guide/540518/all/Staphylococcus_aureus)

[Causes and Symptoms of Tonsillitis](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/tonsillitis/symptoms-causes/syc-20378479)

Comment: Yeah i was at the doctor and i have staph aureus. He told my throat looks clear and he do not want to give me antibiotics so i should gargle salt water with some herbs (but i forgot wich one).(I have some smelling white dots in my tonsils that i am taking out) But gargling salt water do nothing. I used citricidal before like for 10 days and now after short pause 5days and it took only one or two days without citricidal and i have white tongue. I hope citricidal helps :)